# Assistance required Designing website using CSS

Tags: css

I have a question about how to layout the webpages and relate each image together so it can flow together.I have multiple many image that some will be layered partially over each other and some are just side-by-side with some space in between them. as well some pictures will be hyperlinks and some will be hyperlinks wih image changes on hover. as well some will be backgrounds to a links of links. I haven't build a real website before. i Just create applications and I am trying to help my friend with this project
They designed it in PhotoShop,  as well they have given me each piece as separate images:

[image: Sample image]
<sub>(source: [missadventures.ca](http://missadventures.ca/missA_layouts_may25.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Your question is too broad to answer well. However, I would suggest that you find a few good CSS tutorials, especially on absolute positioning of elements.

Comment: the main question is how do i connect them all together. i have figured out how to position items. but if i want all the images in a container which would be centered i want every elements reference to be the containers reference not the browsers edge. you can see what i have done already at: http://www.missadventures.ca/index2.html

Comment: To position an element relative to its container, set the container's CSS to `position:relative` and the child's CSS to `position:absolute`.

Comment: Are your friends aware that their text is filled with spelling and grammatical errors?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bigger question that can be answered here, and you're going to need some more general knowledge on building sites.

First, decide whether you want to hand-code the site or use a WYSIWYG editor. If you want to use a WYSIWYG, [Adobe Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver.html) is easy to use and very good.

Now onto the code part. Regardless of your previous choice, you should have a basic understanding of HTML and CSS just for debugging. These two books helped me immensely when I was starting out:

- [Designing with Web Standards](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321616952)
- [Eric Meyer on CSS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/073571245X)

Along with StackOverflow, you can also use the following sites as learning tools and a reference:

- http://www.alistapart.com
- http://www.thinkvitamin.com
- http://www.devguru.com

Finally, make sure to install the [Firebug debugging tool for Firefox](http://getfirebug.com/)

Good luck!